# Cannot excecute make devserver command

Tags: python-3.x, gnu-make, pelican, static-pages

I am new to pelican and when I try execute the following command it, fails.

```
make devserver
```

It gives me this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `devserver'.  Stop.
```

I am new to pelican and building blogs. Please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `make devserver` from the directory where the `Makefile´ is. So, change to this directory and try again.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.